# Random Float between 0 and 1 in PHP

Tags: php, random

How does one generate a random float between 0 and 1 in PHP?

I'm looking for the PHP's equivalent to Java's `Math.random()`.

Comment: There are a few examples [in the `rand()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

Comment: wouldnt that return me an integer?

Comment: Goaler It is your job as the programmer to make a float value from the int value, using arithmetic. It's in the docs. @dystroy has copied it here for your convenience.

Comment: Ok thanks =) Sorry for any inconvenience (I am more used to Java)

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed.  It seems perfectly legitimate to me.  I browsed through the documentation and couldn't find the answer.  Nominating to reopen.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14155720/89818 and the first comment

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You may use the standard function: [lcg_value()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.lcg-value.php).

Here's another function given on the [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) docs:

```
// auxiliary function
// returns random number with flat distribution from 0 to 1
function random_0_1() 
{
    return (float)rand() / (float)getrandmax();
}
```

Comment: In PHP 4 and 5, `mt_rand()` is preferred over `rand()`, as these generate more random values. `return (float) mt_rand() / (float) mt_getrandmax();`

Comment: In PHP 7.1+ `rand` is now an alias of `mt_rand`

Comment: getrandmax and mt_getrandmax returns 2147483647 even on 64 bit systems. So you can increase resolution using random_int(0, 999999999999999) / 1000000000000000

Answer (score 25):

Example from documentation :

```
function random_float ($min,$max) {
   return ($min+lcg_value()*(abs($max-$min)));
}
```

Comment: +1 This is a more generic method which will return a random float value bounded by a given min and max float value.

Answer (score 8):

```
class SomeHelper
{
     /**
     * Generate random float number.
     *
     * @param float|int $min
     * @param float|int $max
     * @return float
     */
    public static function rand($min = 0, $max = 1)
    {
        return ($min + ($max - $min) * (mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
rand(0,1000)/1000 returns:
0.348 0.716 0.251 0.459 0.893 0.867 0.058 0.955 0.644 0.246 0.292
```

or use a bigger number if you want more digits after decimal point

Answer (score 4):

*update:
forget this answer it doesnt work wit php -v > 5.3*

What about

```
floatVal('0.'.rand(1, 9));
```

?

this works perfect for me,  and it´s not only for 0 - 1 for example between 1.0 - 15.0

```
 floatVal(rand(1, 15).'.'.rand(1, 9));
```

Comment: at least one :D but note this "number-building" has nothing to do with arithmetics, nevertheless its working

Comment: what error do you get ? i just tried with 5.4.36 and my first example just works

Comment: ah i see ,http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/65f71b02a4cfbda5698549892887fcb92f1edc6f

Answer (score 4):

```php
function mt_rand_float($min, $max, $countZero = '0') {
    $countZero = +('1'.$countZero);
    $min = floor($min*$countZero);
    $max = floor($max*$countZero);
    $rand = mt_rand($min, $max) / $countZero;
    return $rand;
}
```

**example:**

```
echo mt_rand_float(0, 1);
```

result: 0.2

```
echo mt_rand_float(3.2, 3.23, '000');
```

result: 3.219

```
echo mt_rand_float(1, 5, '00');
```

result: 4.52

```
echo mt_rand_float(0.56789, 1, '00');
```

result: 0.69

Answer (score 3):

```
$random_number = rand(1,10).".".rand(1,9);
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution for PHP 7. Generates random number in `[0,1)`. i.e. includes 0 and excludes 1.

```
function random_float() {
    return random_int(0, 2**53-1) / (2**53);
}
```

Thanks to `Nommyde` in the comments for pointing out my bug.

```
>>> number_format((2**53-1)/2**53,100)
=> "0.9999999999999998889776975374843459576368331909179687500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
>>> number_format((2**53)/(2**53+1),100)
=> "1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: (PHP_INT_MAX - 1) / PHP_INT_MAX is float 1.0000 exactly. So this function includes 1. If you don't want include 1, use 15 digits or less:
random_int(0, 999999999999999) / 1000000000000000

Comment: @Nommyde Good catch... I thought that might have just been display rounding but it appears to be true. Will tweak my answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
function frand($min, $max, $decimals = 0) {
  $scale = pow(10, $decimals);
  return mt_rand($min * $scale, $max * $scale) / $scale;
}

echo "frand(0, 10, 2) = " . frand(0, 10, 2) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

This question asks for a value from 0 to 1. For most mathematical purposes this is usually invalid albeit to the smallest possible degree. The standard distribution by convention is 0 >= N < 1. You should consider if you really want something inclusive of 1.

Many things that do this absent minded have a one in a couple billion result of an anomalous result. This becomes obvious if you think about performing the operation backwards.

`(int)(random_float() * 10)` would return a value from 0 to 9 with an equal chance of each value. If in one in a billion times it can return 1 then very rarely it will return 10 instead.

Some people would fix this after the fact (to decide that 10 should be 9). Multiplying it by 2 should give around a ~50% chance of 0 or 1 but will also have a ~0.000000000465% chance of returning a 2 like in [Bender's dream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOn_ySghN2Y).

Saying 0 to 1 as a float might be a bit like mistakenly saying 0 to 10 instead of 0 to 9 as ints when you want ten values starting at zero. In this case because of the broad range of possible float values then it's more like accidentally saying 0 to 1000000000 instead of 0 to 999999999.

With 64bit it's exceedingly rare to overflow but in this case some random functions are 32bit internally so it's not no implausible for that one in two and a half billion chance to occur.

The standard solutions would instead want to be like this:

```
mt_rand() / (getrandmax() + 1)
```

There can also be small usually insignificant differences in distribution, for example between 0 to 9 then you might find 0 is slightly more likely than 9 due to precision but this will typically be in the billionth or so and is not as severe as the above issue because the above issue can produce an invalid unexpected out of bounds figure for a calculation that would otherwise be flawless.

Java's Math.random will also never produce a value of 1. Some of this comes from that it is a mouthful to explain specifically what it does. It returns a value from 0 to less than one. It's Zeno's arrow, it never reaches 1. This isn't something someone would conventionally say. Instead people tend to say between 0 and 1 or from 0 to 1 but those are false.

This is somewhat a source of amusement in bug reports. For example, any PHP code using lcg_value without consideration for this may glitch approximately one in a couple billion times if it holds true to its documentation but that makes it painfully difficult to faithfully reproduce.

This kind of off by one error is one of the common sources of "Just turn it off and on again." issues typically encountered in embedded devices.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers are using `mt_rand`. However, `mt_getrandmax()` usually returns only `2147483647`. That means you only have 31 bits of information, while a double has a mantissa with 52 bits, which means there is a density of at least `2^53` for the numbers between 0 and 1.

This more complicated approach will get you a finer distribution:

```
function rand_754_01() {
    // Generate 64 random bits (8 bytes)
    $entropy = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8);
    // Create a string of 12 '0' bits and 52 '1' bits. 
    $x = 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    $first12 = pack("Q", $x);
    // Set the first 12 bits to 0 in the random string. 
    $y = $entropy & $first12;
    // Now set the first 12 bits to be 0[exponent], where exponent is randomly chosen between 1 and 1022. 
    // Here $e has a probability of 0.5 to be 1022, 0.25 to be 1021, etc. 
    $e = 1022;     
    while($e > 1) {   
        if(mt_rand(0,1) == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            --$e;
        }
    }
    // Pack the exponent properly (add four '0' bits behind it and 49 more in front)
    $z = "\0\0\0\0\0\0" . pack("S", $e << 4);
    // Now convert to a double. 
    return unpack("d", $y | $z)[1];          
}
```

Please note that the above code only works on 64-bit machines with a Litte-Endian byte order and Intel-style IEEE754 representation. (`x64`-compatible computers will have this). Unfortunately PHP does not allow bit-shifting past `int32`-sized boundaries, so you have to write a separate function for Big-Endian.

You should replace this line:

```
    $z = "\0\0\0\0\0\0" . pack("S", $e << 4);
```

with its big-endian counterpart:

```
    $z = pack("S", $e << 4) .  "\0\0\0\0\0\0";
```

The difference is only notable when the function is called a large amount of times: `10^9` or more.

**Testing if this works**

It should be obvious that the mantissa follows a nice uniform distribution approximation, but it's less obvious that a sum of a large amount of such distributions (each with cumulatively halved chance and amplitude) is uniform.

Running:

```
function randomNumbers() {
    $f = 0.0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i) {
        $f += \math::rand_754_01();
    }
    echo $f / 1000000;
}
```

Produces an output of `0.49999928273099` (or a similar number close to 0.5).

Comment: there is a simpler way to generate random float between 1 and 2. Then you can just subtract 1:
`$a = random_bytes(8); $a[0] = "\x3f"; $a[1] = $a[1] | "\xf0"; return unpack('E', $a)[1] - 1.0;`

Comment: @Nommyde Floating point precision depends on the absolute size of the value. By subtracting, you lose (some amount of) precision. At values between 1.5 and 2, this is just 1 bit, but a value very close to 1 will lose a large amount of precision. 
I believe my answer allows all non-denormal values to be possible, or 2^52 * (2^10 - 1) values, about 1/4 of all possible floating-point numbers, while that method only has 2^52 possible values, only 1/1024 of all possible floating-point numbers. 
(Exercise for the reader: Find an example of a number generated by one but not the other.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php#example-4017)

```
<?php
function randomFloat($min = 0, $max = 1) {
    return $min + mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax() * ($max - $min);
}

var_dump(randomFloat());
var_dump(randomFloat(2, 20));
?>


float(0.91601131712832)
float(16.511210331931)
```

So you could do

```
randomFloat(0,1);
```

or simple

```
mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax() * 1;
```

Answer (score -3):

what about:

```
echo (float)('0.' . rand(0,99999));
```

would probably work fine... hope it helps you.

Comment: -1 This will not provide a random distribution between 0 and 1.  Consider when the random number returns 24 and it becomes 0.24.  Really, I think you're looking for 0.000024.  The other problem is that half the results will be between 0.1 and 0.2 because the rand will be in the range of 100000 and 199999.