# Random float number between 0 and 1.0 php

Tags: php, random, floating-point, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random Float in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141212/random-float-in-php)

Is it possible to create a random float number between 0 and 1.0 e.g 0.4, 0.8 etc. 
I used rand but it only accepts integers.

Comment: There is an official example to do that in the [PHP Manual for `mt_getrandmax`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php)

Comment: My bad, had a breif look but didnt come across that question

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47190869/89818

Comment: Why not just make it simple. rand(0,1).".".rand(0,100)

Answer (score 127):

```
mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax();
```

Avoid the `rand()` function, since it usually depends on the platform's C `rand()` implementation, generally creating numbers with a very simple pattern. See [this comment on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php#107738)

**Update**: In php 7.1 the `rand()`[has been changed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.rand-srand-aliases) and is now merely an alias of `mt_rand()`. Therefore it is now ok to use `rand()`, too.

Comment: or, to more appropriately simulate the 0.0 inclusive to 1.0 exclusive nature of what I consider a standard randomization routine, use `mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax() - 1) / mt_getrandmax()`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47190869/89818 for a version that supports both the inclusive and the exclusive variant.

Comment: With PHP 7.0 `rand` use the same generator as `mt_rand`. However, there is different behavior with the values of the arguments when `max` is less than `min`.

Comment: [lcg_value()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lcg-value.php) does the job. Far simpler. Unfortunately this question is locked and I cannot create an answer with this. (even though this question is far more popular than its counterpart)

Comment: @Lemmings19 lcg_value() is really what I am looking for. But it always returns 0.xxxx. For a more natural result, I do sum it with rand(). `lcg_value() + rand()` and it will result `1922854540.5079` for example.

Answer (score 39):

What about simply dividing by 10?

```
$randomFloat = rand(0, 10) / 10;
var_dump($randomFloat);

//eg. float(0.7)
```

Comment: Well it will only be 1 of 10 possible choices, not much room for randomness there

Comment: @Dracony The OP only seemed to want 1 decimal. Of course, any number could be picked (`rand(0, 10000) / 10000`) to cause more decimals and hence more randomness.

Comment: @Dracony, h2oooooo: To be pedantic, the amount of randomness doesn't change...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Of course you are correct - it's just as random, but has more decimals.

Comment: @Dracony: ...and now you have my answer :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155603/random-float-number-between-0-and-1-0-php/14155720#14155720

Answer (score 14):

```
$v = mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax();
```

will do that.

---

In case you want only one decimal place (as in the examples from the question) just `round()` the value you get...

```
$v = round( $v, 1 );
```

...or calculate a number between 0 and 10 and divide by 10:

```
$v = mt_rand( 0, 10 ) / 10;
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the PHP documentation, if you're using PHP 7 you can generate a cryptographically secure pseudorandom integer using [random_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)

With that said, here's a function that utilizes this to generate a random float between two numbers:

```
function random_float($min, $max) {
    return random_int($min, $max - 1) + (random_int(0, PHP_INT_MAX - 1) / PHP_INT_MAX );
}
```

Although random_int() is more secure than mt_rand(), keep in mind that it's also slower.

> A previous version of this answer suggested you use PHP rand(), and had a horrible implementation. I wanted to change my answer without repeating what others had already stated, and now here we are.

Comment: The result will not be uniformly distributed, since the 1.0 will have a propability of 0.5. Furthermore you'll only get a resolution of 0.1.

Comment: Took me some time. A few years later. Is this better?

Answer (score 2):

how about this simple solution:

```
abs(1-mt_rand()/mt_rand())
```

or

```
/**
 * Generate Float Random Number
 *
 * @param float $Min Minimal value
 * @param float $Max Maximal value
 * @param int $round The optional number of decimal digits to round to. default 0 means not round
 * @return float Random float value
 */
function float_rand($Min, $Max, $round=0){
    //validate input
    if ($min>$Max) { $min=$Max; $max=$Min; }
        else { $min=$Min; $max=$Max; }
    $randomfloat = $min + mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax() * ($max - $min);
    if($round>0)
        $randomfloat = round($randomfloat,$round);

    return $randomfloat;
}
```

Comment: When using other people's work, please always reference your sources. http://www.ivankristianto.com/php-snippet-code-to-generate-random-float-number/ Thanks!

Comment: There is an error in the code:
These line:
    if ( **$min** >$Max) { $min=$Max; $max=$Min; }
Should be :
    if ( **$Min** >$Max) { $min=$Max; $max=$Min; }

Comment: Also, there is no need to guarantee that `$Min < $Max`—having them swapped yields a mathematically identical probability distribution…

Comment: The first solution is not valid. Dividing two independent uniformly distributed random variables will get you a Uniform Ratio distribution (although computers are always discrete; this is an approximation). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution. There's a probability of 1/4 that it will return a number larger than one (and can return numbers of any size with probability decreasing as the square of the number). 

The uniform ratio distribution is no longer uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
// Generates and prints 100 random number between 0.0 and 1.0 
$max = 1.0;
$min = 0.0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i)
{
    print ("<br>");
    $range = $max - $min;
    $num = $min + $range * (mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax());    
    $num = round($num, 2);
    print ((float) $num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast to float<sup>*</sup> and divide by `getrandmax()`.

---

<sub>* It seems that the cast is unnecessary in PHP's arbitrary type-juggling rules.  It would be in other languages, though.</sub>

Comment: The rules aren't arbitrary.

Comment: @Fuser97381: Maybe not arbitrary, but certainly built up as a series of ad-hoc afterthoughts, resulting in a nasty, inconsistent set of rules.