# Get only random 20% of consecutive inputs

Tags: php, random, statistics

I have a system that constantly gathers items from a rss feed.

I want to take only a certain percentage, say 20%, of those items, randomly.

My approach is that for each item I "throw a dice" using rand(0,100) and accept the item only if the result of this statement is < 20.

Is it a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure your random is truly random, then yes, that is a perfectly fine approach.

Note that it is probably easier to do a random 0, 5 and only accept it when it is 1 (same effect, 20% is 1/5th of a 100). You'll have a narrower distribution that way. Although, this requires a round to integer which is an additional operation.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried also with 0 to 10 and 2, but somehow I always got more than 20% of results (i tried with creating a long array and filtering another array from it with the said conditional statement).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. However, the standard way of selecting values at random is just to simulate from a uniform(0,1) and accept/reject as appropriate. Your pseudo-code is then:

```
if(unif(0,1) < 0.2)
   ##Do something
```

After you select `n` items from a total of `N` entries, you have been sampling from the [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters `N` and `p=0.2`. For example, if `N=10000`, then you would have selected (on average) `N*p=10000*0.2=2000` items. However, the variance will be: `N*p*(1-p) = 1600`. So selecting anywhere between

```
(2000 - 2*sqrt(1600), 2000 + 2*sqrt(1600)) = (1920, 2080)
```

would be reasonable.

Comment: Yep, I thought that rand gives out a uniform distr, and my trials prove that enough.
Hwr including the concept of variance, the numerosity of N of the range give to rand(), reduces a lot the SE of the CI. This somehow decrease the SE even if the N of the sample stays the same. I suppose this is due to the fact that rand() returns only integers, therefore biasing the distribution. Actually my question could be simplified asking whether rand() returns really values from a uniform. The answer could be that, if you increase the range, that becomes increasingly true?

Comment: Don't use rand. Just generate continuous random numbers.  See this question and links for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155603/random-float-number-between-0-and-1-0-php

Comment: ehm which part of the page you linked? hwr i'm using mt_rand now.