# Generate random float numbers in range PHP

Tags: php, random

I have a code that initializes a dice object by the following code:

```
public function initializeDiceSides($totalSides, $fair, $maxProbability = 100) {
   $maxTemp = $maxProbability;
   $sides = array();

   for ($side = 0; $side < $totalSides; $side++) {
     //if we want fair dice just generate same probabilities for each side
     if ($fair === true) {
       $probability = number_format($maxProbability/$totalSides, 5);
     } else {
       //set probability to random number between 1 and half of $maxTemp
       $probability = number_format(mt_rand(1, $maxTemp/2), 5);

       //subtract probability of current side from maxtemp
       $maxTemp= $maxTemp- $probability;

       $sides[$side] = $probability;
     }
   }

   echo $total . '<br />';
   print_r($sides);
}
```

above code prints:

```
89
Array ( [0] => 48.00000 [1] => 13.00000 [2] => 14.00000 
        [3] => 9.00000 [4] => 2.00000 [5] => 2.00000 )
```

I want to be able to generate float numbers instead of integers, I want to have something like

```
Array ( [0] => 48.051212 [1] => 13.661212 [2] => 14.00031 
        [3] => 9.156212 [4] => 2.061512 [5] => 2.00000 )
```

Comment: See the user comments at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lcg-value.php

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155603/random-float-number-between-0-and-1-0-php

Answer (score 10):

A simple approach would be to use `lcg_value` and multiply with the range and add the min value

```
function random_float ($min,$max) {
    return ($min + lcg_value()*(abs($max - $min)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd just generate random numbers from 0 to 999999 and then divide them by 100000

Answer (score 1):

You could multiply the variables that you feed into `mt_random` by a factor of, say, 100000, and then divide the output by the same factor to get a float value.

Answer (score 1):

```
function random_float($min = 0, $max = 1, $includeMax = false) {
    return $min + \mt_rand(0, (\mt_getrandmax() - ($includeMax ? 0 : 1))) / \mt_getrandmax() * ($max - $min);
}
```

Comment: a little explanation about what the code does would go a long way for helping the OP and all community users that would come after the OP looking to learn

Comment: @ochi Thought about that, but it seemed pretty much superfluous. This uses the de facto standard method signature of functions generating random numbers in a range. And the author of the question already knows `mt_rand`, which uses the same two parameters. Finally, the last (third) parameter is really self-explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the value of $maxProbability and $totalSides are floats.
If they are integers, the result will be typed as an integer.